# Erro ao excluir uma referencia de tabela Oracle

Tags: oracle

Estou tentando excluir um registro da minha tabela `TB_CONTATO` que é filha da tabela `TB_CLIENTE`:

```
DELETE FROM TB_CONTATO  WHERE ID_CLIENTE = 2999
```

Porém ocorre de violação de integridade:

```
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SISMET.SYS_C00418600) violated - child record found <br>
```

Esta é a estrutura da tabela filha (`TB_CONTATO`):

```
CREATE TABLE tb_contato (
  id_contato               NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
  id_cliente               NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
  st_nome                  VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
)
  STORAGE (
    NEXT       1024 K
  )
/
PROMPT ALTER TABLE tb_contato ADD CONSTRAINT pk_contato PRIMARY KEY
ALTER TABLE tb_contato
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_contato PRIMARY KEY (
    id_contato
  )
  USING INDEX
    STORAGE (
      NEXT       1024 K
    )
/

PROMPT ALTER TABLE tb_contato ADD FOREIGN KEY
ALTER TABLE tb_contato
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (
    id_cliente
  ) REFERENCES tb_cliente (
    id_cliente
  )
/
GRANT DELETE,INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE ON tb_contato TO sismetop;
```

Executei a linha de comando conforme esse exemplo ([Chave estrangeira de descarte da tabela Oracle Alter](https://razorsql.com/features/oracle_drop_foreign_key.html)):
`ALTER TABLE TB_CONTATO DROP CONSTRAINT SISMET.SYS_C00418600` 
e gerou o seguinte erro:

```
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

Pesquisei em alguns sites por exemplo [Oracle PRIMARY KEY](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-primary-key/), pelo que entendi nicialmente eu faria o seguinte :

```
ALTER TABLE TB_CONTATO
DROP CONSTRAINT pk_nome_da_constraints;
```

No exemplo acima não tenho o nome da constranin, como faço pra eliminar essa referência, essa dependência entre a tabela Filha e a tabela Pail ?

Comment: Já tentou descobrir qual constraint é essa? Tenta rodar uma query assim: SELECT * FROM user_constraints WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%SYS_C00418600';

Comment: Bom dia ! @Daniel Mendes executei essa linha de comando e descobri que o nome da constraint é **pk_contato**, mas esse nome como pode ver no post  é referente a **primary key id_contato** confesso que estou um pouco confuso, pois quero simplesmente retirar a referencia da tabela **TB_CLIENTE** e não excluir a **primary key**.

Comment: Pode ter uma "delete cascade" mal pensada talvez , só vendo toda a estrutura vide https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: No Oracle, as FKs por default tem a opção "ON DELETE NO ACTION" que não apaga referência de FK que está relacionada a alguma PK. Você não tem outra tabela referenciado id_contato? O erro ORA-02292 indica que você tentou apagar algo que possui referência, então, outra tabela está referenciando o (s) id_contato (s) que será (ão) apagado(s) pelo seu comando de delete com filtro em id_cliente = 2999.